# Sitecore workbox compare is not showing shared fields on comparing two version

Tags: workflow, workbox

I have workflow enabled on Sitecore.

When I edit any item and send it to a reviewer, the reviewer is not able to see the shared fields in the compare tab, so any changes made in a shared field, cannot be reviewed.

Is there any way to make the shared fields visible in the compare tab?

Comment: Seems that is not a question. You can address your suggestion into Sitecore support and discuss your vision on an official Sitecore slack chat.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore `Workbox` uses `Diff` dialog to compare versions of an item. Save dialog is used in `Translate` mode in Content Editor. That's why it only shows `Versioned` fields.

I totally agree that it should include `Shared` fields as well, but I don't see any easy way to achieve that.

`DiffForm` class which is used by `Diff` view calls `Compare` method which either runs `OneColumnDiffView.Compare()` or `TwoCoumnsDiffView.Compare()` (depending on the user registry setting).

They both inherit from `DiffView` abstract class which has `protected virtual bool ShowField(Field field)` method, which in the default implementation returns false for `Shared` fields.

So the only solution that I can think of is:

- create new classes inheriting from both `TwoCoumnsDiffView` and `OneColumnDiffView` and override `ShowField` method to make sure that `Shared` fields are shown.
- create new custom `DiffForm` class inheriting from the original `DiffForm` class, decompile the original class and copy the whole code of `OnLoad`, `OnPreRender` and `Refresh` methods + the `Compare` method with a single change - use your custom `TwoCoumnsDiffView` and `OneColumnDiffView` classes there instead of the original classes.
- edit `sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Diff.xml` file and set `CodeBeside` property to your custom `DiffForm`.

It will work but it will be hard to maintain while upgrading to newer Sitecore versions. You will have to double check if everything works.

Is it worth it? That's your (or your client decision).

You may also raise a Sitecore Support decision and explain that the workbox diff view doesn't show `Shared` fields which are changed between the versions and ask them to provide you a patch for the issue. But the only thing they can do is the same what I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks @Marek. I will raise a support ticket for this with Sitecore. I thought there is some issue in our installation that we are not able to see shared fields.